# arrays does not null from beginning

Tags: c

I'm a beginner in C .... I have a little code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(){
   char str1[100];
   char str2[100];
   char str3[100];
   char str4[100];

   puts(str1)
   puts(str2);
   puts(str3);
   puts(str4);

   return 0; 
}
```

I got result

```
2
èý(
‘Q]wØ„ÃîþÿÿÿÀ"bwd&bw
```

I don't know why my array does not empty from the begin. And I have to set first element to "\0" to clear content of array. Can anyone explain for me. Thank a lot.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As for *why* it doesn't automatically zero the string, it's because that would be costly to do so, and C generally doesn't do costly things that you don't explicitly tell it to do. At a minimum, it would have to set the first element of every array to zero,and there are plenty of occasions where you wouldn't want to or need to initialize the array like this. If C always did this for you, then you'd always have that useless overhead that you couldn't get rid of.

As a general rule, C doesn't do anything in the background that you don't explicitly tell it to do, so when you ask for an array, it just gives you an array, and doesn't touch the contents unless you tell it to. It can create a little bit more work for the programmer, but with the benefit of more finely-grained control over exactly what the computer is doing.

Some people would consider that it's a good programming practice to always initialize your variables anyway, and to forget about this kind of tiny cost, and a lot of the time they'll have a good point, but C is deliberately a very flexible and low-level language, and it just doesn't force you to do things like this.

Answer (score 11):

In C, local variables are not initialized automatically if you don't assign values to them. Here your arrays are uninitialized, which means they may contain garbage after their creation.

Yes, you need to explicitly set it to be "empty" like:

```
char str[100];
str[0] = '\0';
// Now you have an empty string of zero length.
assert(strlen(str) == 0);
// But the size is still 100.
printf ("%d", sizeof(str));
```

Alternatively, you can create an empty string(character array) during the initialization. It has the same size and length as the example above.

```
char str[100] = "";
```

Comment: `strlen(str) = 0;` ← this is confusing, at first I thought: why does this even compile (assigning a POD rvalue?) and then I got your point. But I think you should rephrase it.

Comment: @qdii: does the assertion make more sense?

Comment: Yep that's perfect :)

Comment: @Jonathan, thanks for updating it for me. That's what I mean;)

Answer (score 1):

one is getting old when one says "In my days...". But nevertheless, "in my days", people were instructed to first declare variables, and directly afterward initialise variables.

In your case, you can do both together and even more thoroughly in one statement.

The solution of Eric Z is the correct one, that I would also use when I'm working the C-way. But to be complete for you, what age_pan describes is that Java inherently does te following:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    char str1[100] = { 0 };
    char str2[100] = { 0 };
    char str3[100] = { 0 };
    char str4[100] = { 0 };

    puts(str1);
    puts(str2);
    puts(str3);
    puts(str4);

    return 0; 
}
```

The difference is that in the solution of Eric Z only the first character is set to 0, which means that you create a zero length zero terminated string. The Java method (shown in the code above) initialises every little byte to 0.

There are pro's and con's to the Java initialisation. It leads to sloppy programming (some call it easier programming) and it takes time if you don't need initialising. On the other hand, I know very little people that need te extra milliseconds that are lost by the initialisation.

Is it necessary to declare variables above the code, and to initialise them? Certainly not. Is it useful? It most certainly is. It avoids all kinds of errors that take a lot of time to debug.

By the way, you are missing a ; after puts(str1)   :-)

Kind regards,
PB

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you had any trouble if the array doesn't start with "empty". In C, the variables start with random values. Unlike in Java, when you declare a variable, the JVM will initiate it by default.